# MATLAB error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB script that worked perfectly fine; there were no problems with it whatsoever. Then I moved it into the MATLAB toolbox and added it to the cache so I could run it easily from the command line.

However, now that I have moved it into the toolbox, I get these error messages! There were no changes to the script or anything. I moved all of the subfolders and other files related to the script with it.

I have no idea why it is giving me this error message. Even worse, it does not do it every time I run the script! Sometimes if I close MATLAB and open it again, the script runs fine. Sometimes all I have to do is click anything in the GUI and it works! But the next time it won't? Can you help me out here?

These are the two error messages it gives me:

```
??? Too many outputs requested.  Most likely cause is missing [] around
left hand side that has a comma separated list expansion.

Error in ==> trials at 13
picture1 = files1.name;

Error in ==> semjudge>TRIAL_Callback at 285
trials;

??? Error using ==> waitfor
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

And:

```
??? Error using ==> nchoosek at 31
The first argument has to be a scalar or a vector.

Error in ==> semjudge>START_Callback at 194
combos = nchoosek(1:nFiles, 2);

??? Error using ==> waitfor
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

What causes these errors, such that they only SOMETIMES appear (without any change in the .m file or the GUI or anything ...)?

This is frustrating me to no end. It was working perfectly fine, and stopped despite no changes being made. And it is inconsistent whether or not it gives me the error. I can't find any pattern to when it does work, and when it doesn't. And neither of the errors that it DOES give me make any sense to me.

The .m file(s) are too long to post here, so you can see them, here:

http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=cKokK (semjudge.m)
http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=vB9sD (trials.m)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your script is not always able to find certain image files.

In trials.m `files1` is probably an empty struct array so the assignment to picture fails. This can be caused by dir not finding appropriate files.

In semjudge.m, if there are no files, `nFiles` is 0, so `1:nFiles` is the empty array.

Comment: Any idea what may be causing this to happen? Or how I fix it? The pictures certainly exist, and the script works sometimes. Why would it only occasionally not find the image files?